Is relying on just the confusion matrix for highly imbalanced test sets to evaluate model performance a bad idea?
I have a binary classification model with a test set that is highly skewed, the majority class 0 is 22 times greater than the minority class 1.
This causes my Precision to be low and Recall to be high, but overall F1 score to be poor. Therefore, I decided to use the confusion matrix to evaluate the model's performance.
Based on what I see the performance does not look poor on the confusion matrix. I am achieving these results for my test set with the BalancedRandomForestClassifier:
Class 0: 8941 // 11061 correct predictions
Class 1: 476 // 522 correct predictions
If I increase the probability thresholds, I can bring down the FPs rate at the cost of a slight increase in FNs. I will like to ask in situations like this, whether it is okay to rely on the confusion matrix.

As always, the answer is "it depends on what is important in your particular application".  Since we don't know what the application is, then we can't give a simple direct answer.
If your application requires a binary classification (rather than an estimate of the probability of class membership or a ranking of the tendency to belong to a particular class) then you should be using some performance metric that depends on the binary classification, so you ought to be using the confusion matrix.
If you want to experiment with false-positive and false-negative error rates, then that suggests that some kinds of errors are more important than others, in which case you should research the costs of different types of misclassification and build those into your performance metric, i.e. the expected loss or risk.  See "cost sensitive learning".
However, I generally would not rely on any single performance metric, but would use a variety that probe different aspects of performance, so I would use error rate (or better still expected misclassification loss) to assess the threshold used to binarise the outcome, but I might also use the AUROC to assess the ranking properties, and a proper scoring rule, such as the Brier score or the log-loss to measure the calibration of the probabilistic output (before thresholding).  Having a range of metrics often helps diagnose problems with models faster as it enables you to narrow in one what is causing the problem.
In many practical applications, we may need a reject option (not classify cases where the classifier is unsure) or we don't know what the misclassification costs are at time of training (or they are variable) or equivalently the relative proportions of classes may be different in operation (or variable).  In such cases, you want to use a probabilistic classifier, as you can deal with all of those issues after training, in which case proper scoring rules are better primary metrics.
As for accuracy being problematic - it isn't as long as you bear in mind what it actually means.  Never just look at accuracy without also giving the baseline from classifying everything as the majority class to put it into context.  Alternatively just use Cohen's kappa statistic (which is accuracy but with an affine transform so that just guessing gives a score of zero and a perfect classifier gives a score of 1).  This is just an affine transform of accuracy, so it is telling you exactly the same thing.  Saying accuracy is bad but Cohen's kappa is good is a bit like saying that Celcius is bad and Kelvin is good.
So basically, the first thing to do is to work out what is important for your application.

No.
The confusion matrix does not give you more information than precision, recall, F1 and accuracy, and all of these are highly problematic for unbalanced data (and "merely" problematic for "balanced" data): Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?
Better to use probabilistic predictions and assess these using proper scoring rules.


If I increase the probability thresholds

This tells me that you have a model that does not output discrete classes. Consequently, when you look at the confusion matrix, you are not looking at the confusion matrix of just the model (which does no classification). You are evaluating the two-step pipeline of some machine learning model (e.g., logistic regression or neural network) followed by a classification rule based on assessing if model predictions fall above or below some threshold value.
There is a confusion matrix for each threshold value. Please feel free to calculate the confusion matrix at other thresholds.
I am with Stephan Kolassa that the raw model predictions yield useful information that is lost upon thresholding, and I would usually advocate for assessing these raw predictions, but if you must classify (I have my doubts, but let’s set them aside), please do feel free to evaluate all aspects of the classifier, including the threshold. If the accuracy/sensitivity/specificity/precision/recall/PPV/NPV/MCC/confusion matrix/whatever is the right way to measure the performance of your classification pipeline, then calculate it, sure.
By default, sklearn predicts the category with the highest probability (above $0.5$ for binary problems) in its predict method. In imbalanced problems, it might be that few or none of the minority-class members are predicted to belong to the minority class with such a high probability. The minority class might always be unusual.
Frank Harrell has two good blog posts about working with the probability predictions. Before you insist on classifying, it is worth knowing this material.
Classification vs. Prediction
Damage Caused by Classification Accuracy and Other Discontinuous Improper Accuracy Scoring Rules
